# HMS Map shows empty

Tags: huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

1. Device information and SDK version

   (a) Phone model (Settings > About phone): Android Emulator

   (b) EMUI version (Settings > About phone): N/A

   (c) HMS Core version number (Settings > Apps > Apps > HMS Core): 5.1.1.303

   (d) SDK version number (app-level build.gradle document): Flutter package:huawei_map: ^5.0.3+302
2. I have 2 questions regarding Map Kit:

   (a) I have downloaded Huawei App Gallery & HMS Core, when I try to debug on an Android emulator (or even real Samsung device), after running my app, Map is not showing It's   totally empty (Please see the attached Screenshot ).

   (b) The Map Kit is unable to be debug on Cloud Debugging, I read this github issue. I would like to know when Cloud Debugging will support the latest HMS Core?
3. What conditions triggered the problem? Does it happen all the time or randomly? :  All the time

[empty_map_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCe8w.png)

**Log**

I/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): 11536-11536|null|com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule|b|104|No available cached loader, query remote. W/Gralloc4(11536): allocator 3.x is not supported I/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): 11536-11536|null|com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule|d|112|bundle info: errorCode:0, moduleVersion:50100300, modulePath:/data/user_de/0/com.huawei.hwid/files/modules/external/huawei_module_maps/50100300/Map-Route.apk, loader_version:50100300, loaderPath:/data/user_de/0/com.huawei.hwid/files/modules/external/huawei_module_maps/50100300/Map-Route.apk, armeabiType:0 W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): 11536-11536|null|com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule|c|84|The loader_path:/data/user_de/0/com.huawei.hwid/files/modules/external/huawei_module_maps/50100300/Map-Route.apk in query bundle is not available,change the module version to:-100 W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): 11536-11536|null|com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule|b|226|failed to load. W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): java.lang.NullPointerException W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.common.util.Logger.a(Unknown Source:27) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.common.util.Logger.w(Unknown Source:9) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.b(Unknown Source:226) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.getRemoteModuleInfo(Unknown Source:45) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.a.e.getModuleInfo(Unknown Source:0) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.load(Unknown Source:22) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.maps.mbu.c(Unknown Source:5) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.maps.mbu.b(Unknown Source:8) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.maps.mbu.a(Unknown Source:15) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView$maa.createDelegate(Unknown Source:57) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.a(Unknown Source:44) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source:5) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source:29) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.flutter.map.map.MapController.init(MapController.java:139) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.flutter.map.map.MapBuilder.build(MapBuilder.java:67) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at com.huawei.hms.flutter.map.map.MapFactory.create(MapFactory.java:87) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:186) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:419) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:313) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:257) W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(11536): 11536-11536|null|com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule|getLocalVersion|90|Cannot find the class of module descriptor for huawei_module_maps I/dynamic-api_e(11536): 11536-11536|null|com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.a.e|getModuleInfo|90|Cannot get module info in remote or local. E/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_8(11536): getRemoteContext: DynamicModule load failedcom.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule$LoadingException: Query remote version and local version failed. E/HmsMapKit_MapCreator_57(11536): getRemoteMapContext failed D/HmsMapKit_MapView_163(11536): getMapAsync:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Map kit starts to support non-Huawei device from **5.1.0.300**. The flutter plugin doesn't support the latest Map kit by default. It causes of empty Map in Non-Huawei devices.

In this case, you will get the log as below :

**02-10 15:49:04.330 W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(24697): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 15:49:04.330 W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(24697):  at com.huawei.hms.common.util.Logger.a(Unknown Source:27)
02-10 15:49:04.330 W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(24697):  at com.huawei.hms.common.util.Logger.w(Unknown Source:9)
02-10 15:49:04.330 W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(24697):  at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.b(Unknown Source:226)
02-10 15:49:04.330 W/dynamic-api_DynamicModule(24697):  at com.huawei.hms.feature.dynamic.DynamicModule.getRemoteModuleInfo(Unknown Source:45)**

So, it is suggested to update the SDK version like below:

[Flutter_MapSDK_App_level_build.gradle_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqgso.png)

[Map_kit_version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUcsh.png)

Then you can use the latest Map kit in your app.